# Wordpress plugin for Frontend Content Entry form?

Tags: wordpress

Is there a wordpress plugin for content entry from Frontend i mean a user logs into the site and does not need to enter the dashboard for content entry it utlizes a form at the frontend.

Comment: See e.g. http://wpmu.org/8-wordpress-plugins-that-enable-posting-and-editing-from-the-front-end/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are some plugins for front end post submission. Try this.

[Post from site](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/post-from-site/)

[Quick post widget](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/quick-post-widget/)

[Posthaste](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/posthaste/)

[Advaced Custom Fields](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) ([Forms](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/create-a-front-end-form/))

Answer (score 0):

This plugin is fairly popular and may help you: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/front-end-editor/

Comment: is not downloadable. i think the resource does not exist

Answer (score 0):

there is a sample plugin available try it.

http://kvcodes.com/2014/02/front-end-post-submission-wordpress/